# TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument with Tensorboard PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, tensorboard

I am trying to write my model to `tensorboard` with the following code:

```
model = SimpleLSTM(4, HIDDEN_DIM, HIDDEN_LAYERS, 1, BATCH_SIZE, device)
writer = tb.SummaryWriter(log_dir=tb_path)
sample_data = iter(trainloader).next()[0]
writer.add_graph(model, sample_data.to(device))
```

I get the error: `TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'batch_size'`

My model looks like this:

```
class SimpleLSTM(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_dims, hidden_units, hidden_layers, out, batch_size, device):
        super(SimpleLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.input_dims = input_dims
        self.hidden_units = hidden_units
        self.hidden_layers = hidden_layers
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.device = device
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.input_dims, self.hidden_units, self.hidden_layers,
                            batch_first=True, bidirectional=False)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(self.hidden_units, out)

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):

        hidden = torch.rand(self.hidden_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_units, device=self.device, dtype=torch.float32)
        cell = torch.rand(self.hidden_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_units, device=self.device, dtype=torch.float32)
        hidden = nn.init.xavier_normal_(hidden)
        cell = nn.init.xavier_normal_(cell)
        return (hidden, cell)

    def forward(self, input, batch_size):
        hidden = self.init_hidden(batch_size)  incomplete batch
        lstm_out, (h_n, c_n) = self.lstm(input, hidden)
        raw_out = self.output_layer(h_n[-1])
        return raw_out
```

How can I write this model to TensorBoard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model takes two arguments `input` and `batch_size`, but you only provide one argument for `add_graph` to call your model with.

The inputs (second argument to `add_graph`) should be a tuple with the `input` and the `batch_size`:

```py
writer.add_graph(model, (sample_data.to(device), BATCH_SIZE))
```

You don't really need to provide the batch size to the forward method, because you can infer it from the input. As your LSTM uses `batch_first=True`, it means that the input is required to have size *[batch_size, seq_len, num_features]*, therefore the size of the first dimension is the current batch size.

```py
def forward(self, input):
    batch_size = input.size(0)
    # ...
```